# Getting error: find: missing argument to `-exec' when using cron job to remove temp files

Tags: cache, session, cron, reports

I am trying to create a cron job that deletes any temp files after certain periods of time.

In crontab I have this:

```
MAILTO:="my@e-mail.com"
@hourly /var/www/magento/cache.sh
```

And in cache.sh there is the following:

```
find /var/www/magento/var/cache/ -type f -mmin +120 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/www/magento/var/session/ -type f -mmin +120 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/www/magento/var/report/ -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
find /var/www/magento/var/tmp/ -mtime +1 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

However the e-mail output is this:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
find: missing argument to `-exec'
rm: cannot remove `/var/www/magento/var/tmp/': Is a directory
```

I'm quite new to cron jobs, does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not really about Magento

Answer (score 0):

sudo find /var/www/html/erp/var/log/ -type f -exec rm -rf {} +

Comment: Care to expand?

Comment: this wil also work,
find /var/www/html/erp/var/log/ -type f -exec rm {} \;
i have doubt on the -mmin +120